# "What I envision" or "what I envisioned"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the two is grammatically correct:

- '... and knew it was exactly what I *envisioned* as the beginning of ...'
- '... and knew it was exactly what I *envision* as the beginning of ...'

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is in past tense so, **envisioned** is the correct one.

Similar question here; https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/72302.

Comment: Hello @Atajera, please elaborate why it's correct.

Comment: This does not seem correct. Although the action is in the past, the subject could have been picturing the future, no?

Comment: This answer is **wrong**. Just because one clause is in past tense, doesn't mean the other must be. Hence @KJO's example. Other examples: "I knew that ice is frozen water" (past with present), "I knew that the Sun will become a white dwarf one day" (past with future), etc.

Comment: Check this out https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/72302

Comment: You should use "would" when you want to project future from the past, not with "will"